# How can I have a NavigationLink with a programmatically defined destination?

Tags: swiftui

So I am working on a list view, where tapping an item on the list opens the detail view for that item.

I also want to have a button which adds an item to the list, and immediately opens the detail view.

Something like this:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    init() {
        self.id = UUID()
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let item: UUID
}

struct ContainerView: View {

    @State var items: [Item] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in 
                    NavigationLink(
                        "Item: \(item.id)",
                        destination: DetailView(item:item)
                    )
                }
            }

            Button("New Item") {
                let newItem = Item()
                items += [newItem]
                // now I want to go to DetailView(item:newItem)
                // how do I set the navigation link target here?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

I see there is this method for programmatic navigation:

```
NavigationItem.init<S, V>(S, tag: V, selection: Binding<V?>, destination: () -> Destination)
```

But I think this will not work as the tag is not known ahead of time.

Answer (score -1):

You almost got it, remember that a `NavigationLink` can only "navigate" inside `NavigationView`

```
    import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    init() {
        self.id = UUID()
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let item: UUID
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("I'm the item \(item)")
    }
}

struct ContainerView: View {
    
    @State var items: [Item] = []
    @State var activeItem: UUID?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: DetailView(item: item.id),
                            tag: item.id,
                            selection: $activeItem
                        ){
                           Text("Item: \(item.id)")
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Button("New Item") {
                    let newItem = Item()
                    items += [newItem]
                    self.activeItem = newItem.id
                    // now I want to go to DetailView(item:newItem)
                    // how do I set the navigation link target here?
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Main View")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: No I don't think you got it.  I want to navigate programmatically when I tap "new item", I don't want to have to tap on the list item after it's created.

Comment: @sak I updated the answer, I believe that's what you're looking for

Comment: The problem you'll have in this implementation is when the list is larger than the screen the navigationlink for the new item wont activate. You could try scrolling to it however that can be error prone. Another way would be to use a sheet for the new item (then it would also be easily cancellable) and only use navigationlink for existing items.